# Passing array to view in Laravel(php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass an array to blade view in Laravel. 
Here is my code in controller:

```
$event_nav= array();
       $event_nav[] = DB::table('tr_visit')
           ->join ('tm_child','tr_visit.Child_ID','=','tm_child.Child_ID')
           ->where('tr_visit.Child_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $childName . '%')
           ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(Visit_Date)'))
           ->distinct()
           ->get();
 return view('ProfilAnak.BmiAnak.seeBmi',compact('event_nav'));
```

and here is my view:

```
    @foreach($event_nav as $year)
       {{$event_nav[0]}}
    @endforeach
```

I'm getting following error message :

> "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
->select(DB::raw('YEAR(Visit_Date)'))
```

with

```
->select(DB::raw('YEAR(Visit_Date) AS Visit_Date'))
```

and in view do this

```
@foreach($event_nav as $year)
   {{$year->Visit_Date}}
@endforeach
```

like @Narendra Sisodia said

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like this

```
@foreach($event_nav[0] as $year)
       {{$year->Child_ID}}
       {{$year->blah}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: in @event_nav i just want select Year of Visit Date.. so how can i make it in view? {{$year->Visit_Date}} not working

Comment: ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(Visit_Date) AS Visit_Date'))

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing over here is same as echoing an array using `echo` so you need to update your code as

```
@foreach($event_nav as $year)
   {{$year->Visit_Date}}
@endforeach
```